# I keep having this error, There is no row at position 0 but records are DB

Tags: c#, dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmfZx.png)

```cs
string FinancialYear_ID = (DatabaseAccess.Retrive("select top 1 FinancialYearID from FinancialYearTable where IsActive  = 1") != null
    ? Convert.ToString(DatabaseAccess.Retrive("select top 1 FinancialYearID from FinancialYearTable where IsActive  = 1").Rows[0][0])
    : string.Empty);
```

Comment: What does your table FinancialYearTable look like? does it have any row which has IsActive set to 1? Are you connecting to exact environment/server?

Comment: You must [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) your `DatabaseAccess.Retrive` method (or explain where this method comes from, if it is not yours). And please, do not post images of your code.

Comment: Yes, on the FinancialYearTable i have a row which has IsActive but i dont know if it is set to one. I'm new to programming

Comment: I don't know what kind of database you have, but they all have tools that allow you to view their contents without having to program anything.

Answer (score 2):

At first an advice: your code looks like it makes two roundtrips to your database (one in the check and another in the conversion), which is not good.

Second (with some guessing, as the question does not contain all necessary information): The call to `DatabaseAccess.Retrive(...)` returns an object which obviously has an array property `Rows`. This object is returned even if the array is empty (otherwise a `NullReferenceException` would have been thrown ).
So your null-check is not what you intended as it doesn't yield any information about the data returned. Try this instead:

```cs
var rows = DatabaseAccess.Retrive(...).Rows;
var FinancialYear_ID = (rows.Length == 0)
    ? string.Empty
    : Convert.ToString(rows[0][0]);
```

If the `Rows` property is not an array you might need to modify the check to `rows.Count` or `!rows.Any()` (using LINQ).

You might also want to add a `null` check for the result of `DatabaseAccess.Retrive(...)`.

But all that depends on the definition of your method.

And maybe fix the typo in `Retrive` ;-)